# appending records in xml structure with php but not xml file but a text file

Tags: php, html

I'm looking for a method to append email addresses from a form to a text file in the little structure that I gave it.

Here is my structure..

```
<email>
 <field id="email1">
  <value></value>
 </field>
 <field id="email2">
  <value></value>
 </field>
 <field id="email3">
  <value></value>
 </field>
<field id="email4">
 <value></value>
</field>
</email>
```

I want to do this with php and not js with getelementbyid as I'm trying to learn php and the more exercises the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this empty XML:

```
$xml   = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><email/>';
```

We want add it this email address:

```
$email = 'someone@some.where';
```

---

#### With DOMDocument:

With `DOMDocument` we have to init the object, to load XML, to set `->formatOutput` (if we want an indented output) and to init `DOMXPath` to perform complex XML searches:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$dom->formatOutput = True;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
```

Then we search for the last `<field>` element with id starting by “email”:

```
$found = $xpath->query( '(//field[starts-with(@id,"email")])[last()]' );
```

If the item is found (not in our case, because we have an empty XML, but sure in next case), we get id attribute and, using `substr`, we extract from it the last id number, then we increment it by 1 to set id of new added email. If no item is found, we set new id to “email1”:

```
if( $found->length )
{
    $oldId = substr( $found->item(0)->getAttribute('id'), 5 );
    $newId = 'email' . ( $oldId + 1 );
}
else
{
    $newId = 'email1';
}
```

At this point, we create the `<field>` child node and we set id attribute:

```
$child = $dom->createElement( 'field' );
$child->setAttribute( 'id', $newId );
```

Then, we append to it the `<value>` node with new email as value:

```
$child->appendChild( $dom->createElement( 'value', $email ) );
```

At the end, we append `$child` node to main `<email>` node:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName( 'email' )->item(0)->appendChild( $child );
```

To print modified XML:

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

In this <kbd>**[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/545920)**</kbd> you can see the result after adding two email addresses.

---

#### With SimpleXML:

With `SimpleXML` we can't format output, but the start is more concise. We load the XML and directly we can search for XPath pattern:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string( $xml );
$found = $sxml->xpath( '(//field[starts-with(@id,"email")])[last()]' );
```

In this case, the result is an array, so we perform the id check using array syntax, also for retrieve id attribute:

```
if( count( $found ) )
{
    $oldId = substr( $found[0]['id'], 5 );
    $newId = 'email' . ( $oldId + 1 );
}
else
{
    $newId = 'email1';
}
```

The syntax for adding the child is very similar to `DOMDocument`:

```
$child = $sxml->addChild( 'field' );
$child->addAttribute( 'id', $newId );
$child->addChild( 'value', $email );
```

To print modified XML:

```
echo $sxml->asXML();
```

---

`SimpleXML` use a syntax more concise and comfortable than `DOMDocument` and, by general opinion, is faster. Conversely, `DOMDocument` is more powerful and customizable.

---

#### XPath pattern explained:

```
                 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                 │                                            ┌───┴────┐
                 │                 retrieve only last node of this query
┌────────────────┴────────────────┐┌──┴───┐
(//field[starts-with(@id,"email")])[last()]
 └─┬─────────────────────────────┘
 ┌─┘
//              find following patter no matter where it is
field           <field> node
[               with
 starts-with    ┐ attribute “id”
 (@id,"email")  ┘ starts with “email”
]
```

---

- Read more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- Read more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
- Read more about [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)